# gsub/regex: deleting begining and end special characters in a factor variable

Tags: regex, r, string, character, gsub

I'm working with the following vector:

```
vec <- c("[0.81, 1]", "0.00 - 0.03", "0.04 - 0.27",  "0.28 - 0.5",  "0.51 - 0.8")
```

I'm interested in amending the value in the value **"[0.81, 1]"** so it corresponds to the format **number - number**

## Working solution

Presently I address this requirement in a following manner:

```
vec <- gsub("\\[", "", vec, perl = TRUE)
vec <- gsub("\\]", "", vec, perl = TRUE)
vec <- gsub(",", " - ", vec, fixed = TRUE)
```

The code produces desired requirements:

```
> vec
[1] "0.81 -  1"   "0.00 - 0.03" "0.04 - 0.27" "0.28 - 0.5"  "0.51 - 0.8"
```

## Problem

I  would like to achieve my solution using a more complex `gsub` with a more fancy `regex`. I would like to come up with `regex` syntax that would:

- Match first **[** and the last **]** and delete them / replace them with nothing
- Or even better, delete the **[** and **]** and signs and insert the **-** instead of the **,** in the middle. I'm guessing that this may involve making use of `gsubfn` so I'm less keen on this solution

On principle I would like to achieve reduce the number of `gsub` calls.

---

## Attempts

I tried something like that:

- `\[(?![[:alnum:]])\]` - it doesn't match anything
- `\[(.*)\]` - appears to matching the whole thing

---

What I would like to achieve:

1. Merge first two `gsub` calls into one
2. If possible, merge all 3 calls into one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use capture groups like this:

```
sub("\\[(.*), (.*)\\]", "\\1 - \\2", vec)
## [1] "0.81 - 1"    "0.00 - 0.03" "0.04 - 0.27" "0.28 - 0.5"  "0.51 - 0.8"
```

Here is a visualization of the regular expression used:

```
\[(.*), (.*)\]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/shvWwZ3jozJkKMCr)

Comment: Thanks very much for a neat solution. Can I ask, with respect to the syntax `"\\1 - \\2"` what does it do in terms of replacing the values I reckon that `\\` escapes character?

Comment: \\1 is the first capture group, i.e. the part matched by the part of the regular expression between the first pair of (...) in it and \\2 is the second.  Try `sub("\\[(.*), (.*)\\]", "\\1", vec)` and `sub("\\[(.*), (.*)\\]", "\\2", vec)` to see this more clearly.

Comment: Thank you very much for the useful and informative answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not one regex, maybe a regexpert will give one, but I combined your first two calls with the second in a oneliner:

```
v1 <- gsub("\\[|\\]","",gsub(","," -",vec))
```

Note that I replaced with " -", and not with " - " as there are already spaces after your comma.